# How to remove all non-ASCII characters from files?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, ascii

I want to  remove all non-ASCII characters from all .tex files in a directory. I know I can use the code:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -dc '\0-\177' <file >newfile
```

for each single file, but I have 200 .tex files. How I can apply this command to all .tex files in the directory and replace each file with a new clean one with the same name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `sed` with in-place replace:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i 's/[^\x0-\xB1]//g' multiplefiles*.tex
```

link to [ASCII-table](https://www.ascii-code.com/)

- `\d0-\d177`: Decimal
- `\x0-\xB1`: Hex
- `\o0-\o261`: Octal

Answer (score 4):

This might do what you want:

```
strings [infile] > [outfile]
```